# Would a Senior Frontend Developer salary in Poland of 9950 - 14920 PLN be a monthly or yearly salary?

Tags: currency, salary

A company in Wrocław Poland advertises a job of Senior Frontend Developer for a salary of "9 950 - 14 920 PLN gross on an employment contract (UoP)"

https://www.monterail.com/careers/senior-frontend-developer-wroclaw

14,920 PLN = $3,822 US Dollars

Does that salary sound like it is monthly or yearly?

Comment: According to [SalaryExporer.com](http://www.salaryexplorer.com/salary-survey.php?loc=173&loctype=1) the average monthly wage in Poland is currently 18,000 PLN.

Comment: @user41790 The number from that source is an outlier. The average monthly wage in Poland [appears](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_European_countries_by_average_wage) to be much [lower](https://www.polandunraveled.com/average-salary-in-poland/), less than 5000 PLN.

Comment: @nanoman Yes, their methodology is rather novel.  It gives an average UK salary as being over GBP100,000 while the US average is given at about USD80,000.

Comment: This website is very much not trustworthy; at least it needs some serious factchecking. For example for Denmark it states that the average monthly salary is 137,000 (~21,000 US dollars). This is about 5 times more than the actual average salary. Seemingly they are switching up *yearly* and *monthly* a lot and hence comparing bananas and pears.

Comment: Yeah, that numbers are totally bonkers. It must be based on some VERY small data set. The top range given at 79.8k also is very funny - i think noone would get that as salary (taxed at 32%) when as entrepeneur you can only pay 17% tax. I also would suggest that all the low paid people do not asnwer those questionaires, so you do get a VERY skewed median.

Answer (score 7):

On the basis that Polish salaries seem to be most often stated per month, and that a software developer job should have an above-average salary, common sense indicates that this is monthly. Moreover, the [minimum wage in Poland](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_wage_in_Poland) is 2600 PLN per month, so it would not be legal to pay less than 31200 PLN per year.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know whether it’s a weekly, monthly or annual salary. What I do know is that you won’t survive in Poland on $3.823 a year.